# Login users are only able to watch the videos they had purchased

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, video

I had looked through the threads and there are few similar questions but I wish to programme it in fully jQuery with AJAX to communicate to PHP.

So I had this list of users and videos but the users may choose to purchase certain videos or all; it is solely up to them. So may I know how do I make it work that when the users view the list of videos, the videos being purchased will have a "Watch" button while videos that are not purchased, will have a "Purchase" button beside.

Any helps or comments are welcome!! Thank you!

Comment: Make a login system. Make a cross-ref table between users and purchased videos (or a field in the users table, or from the purchases table itself if you have one). Echo the purchase/watch buttons based on whether the user has purchased it or not. Write the jQuery and Ajax functions for those buttons. Put server-side validation before serving or saving any info. Now, when you have all this done (or get stuck somewhere in the process), come to SO and make a more specific question. `:)`

Comment: Hi, I had tried doing so but now the problem is to check which TR has the video that is not being purchase. Do I use .each()?

Comment: I had managed to solve it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new table to store video_id and user_id then using session variable retrieve the playable video from the database that matches the user_id stored in the session.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_videos WHERE user_id='$_SESSION["user_id']'";
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying out now :)

Comment: Hi, I had tried doing so but now the problem is to check which TR has the video that is not being purchase. Do I use .each()?

Comment: I had managed to solve it! Thank you.